# how can i change highlight color in mupdf library android

Tags: android, mupdf

My project is using mupdf for android.I am not able to change color of highlighted text.Anyone who can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mupdf library they have used some default color for highlight as below

```
 color[0] = 1.0;
 color[1] = 1.0;
 color[2] = 0.0;
```

To change the color dynamically, You can pass the integer color value as a parameter to the corresponding method and assign it like below.

```
color[0] = ((intcolor >> 16) & 0xFF) / 255.0;  // Extract the RR byte
color[1] = ((intcolor >> 8) & 0xFF) / 255.0;   // Extract the GG byte
color[2] = (intcolor & 0xFF) / 255.0; // Extract the BB byte
```

Comment: Where can i find this line of code.i am not able to find.can you please help me.. @Ramesh R

Comment: u can find it in addMarkupAnnotationInternal() of mupdf.c class.here is the link :http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob;f=platform/android/jni/mupdf.c#l1514

Comment: intcolor=239936 pass color code. and i will set this code but not change anything. also display yellow color. please give me answer. @RameshR –   user4769068

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers Code i have added works for ARGB color code. try to pass ARGB color int value and check.